issue facing in azure kops export path of storage Location KOPS_STATE_STORE
Error: error building path for "https://myk8sstate.kubrg.blob.core.windows.net": unknown / unhandled path type: "https://myk8sstate.kubrg.blob.core.windows.net"
Error: error building path for "azure://myk8sstate.kubrg.blob.core.windows.net": unknown / unhandled path type: "azure://myk8sstate.kubrg.blob.core.windows.net"
how can i assign container url path to environment variables to launch kops cluster azure ubuntu server
how can i fix it ????
